# Did the Romans ever get the idea to pardon Jesus or expunge the conviction when they adopted it as the state religion in 380, Edict of Thessalonica?

Tags: ancient-rome, roman-empire, christianity, byzantine-empire, jesus

Given the premise of Jesus as being an innocent man being wrongfully convicted, wouldn't the very legally minded Romans or other jurists have the idea that the government should delete the conviction so as to make Jesus no longer a traitor in the eyes of the government? They had almost 1100 years to do it if the Roman government wanted to, I would think someone would have the idea.

Comment: That's the opening of a debate, not a real question. Sorry. We don't do that here.

Comment: The question might be more profitably phrased something like, "Was there something in the Roman law or the Roman conception of law which mitigated against Rome, once it was a Christian Empire, reversing the guilty verdict against Jesus." (I think that's the gist of your question.)

Comment: @MarkOlson the concept of posthumous rehabilitation or decoration was very rare in the Roman empire.

Comment: @Jos: Rome also wasn't big on admitting failure - even centuries old failure.

Comment: You are looking for a *restitutio memoriae*, but that didn't exist in Roman Law. At the most, Ulpianus in the *Digesta* (Book 28) talks about the honor of the deceased but only in terms of their will. So, the only option would be a *restitutio in integrum* to "repair" Jesus' right, but that wasn't possible in a sentenced to death because the *restitutio* was part of the formulary process and only the person affected and their direct heirs could initiate it in front of the *praetor* and be present during the *interrogatio*, which was a crucial part of the process.

Comment: Christianity includes the theological idea that mankind (Jews, Romans, Greeks, whatever, including the apostles, including Peter, who denies him etc - even people past and future: "*we would all have done the same!*") is guilty for Jesus' condemnation, something like a second original sin, and being a christian was all about atoning for that. Trying to fix it by legalistic procedure was contradicting this idea or worldview. In a way, application of Roman law on a theological matter would have meant a perpetuation of pre-Christian  thought, so the two were unsurprisingly kept separate.

Comment: @Jos - I vote for reopening: The OP asks about the existence or absence of a fact (legal initiative of some kind to revise a past action). I don't see why that is not a question.

Comment: And, as now, a couple of comments include things that could be part of a good historical answer.

Comment: More interesting would be the question 'Did the Roman Empire keep records of all convictions carried out during its rule?'

Comment: [Documenting preliminary research will improve both the probability of an answer and the quality of the answer(s)](https://history.meta.stackexchange.com/a/785/26786)  Are there any records of Roman legal posthumous pardons?

Comment: @T.E.D. IIRC  (just from the Bible) it was on charges of heresy (claiming to be the Messiah) and it was the Sanhedrin who condemned him; Roman intervention was just because they were the only ones who could execute the sentence. Hence, Pilate's intervention was more an omission (he saw no value in opposing the Sanhedrin in a purely Jewish affair) than the Romans actually seeing Jesus as a criminal or a danger. Of course, this narrative would make it easier for non-Jewish Romans to accept Christianism, as he would not have been an anti-Roman character.

Comment: @SJuan76 - You're right, I was misremembering things. Looking at it, all 4 gospels say the charge was claiming to be King of the Jews (which could well be viewed as a challenge to Roman authority, since that title was the Emperor's to bestow).